# How does Wordpress convert directory requests into database generated pages?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache

This is a curiosity based question, rather than being related to any issue.

I wondered how Wordpress rectifies pseudo URL addresses (e.g. blog.com/posts/2015/05/05/example_blog_post) to php generated pages? What are the mechanics behind this redirection process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a rule from the server config, not the CMS specifically. For instance, the [common Apache config](https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/) is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

The second-to-last line if "if URL does not exist as a directory, also pass this on to WordPress".

The rest is handled by the [rewrite engine](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rewrite/) which is a bunch of compiled regular expressions. If you have the WordPress CLI you can run `wp rewrite list` and it will show you the entire list in priority order:

| match | query | source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (.?.+?)/embed/?$ | index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&embed=true | page |
| (.?.+?)/trackback/?$ | index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&tb=1 | page |
| (.?.+?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$ | index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2] | page |
| (.?.+?)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$ | index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2] | page |
| (.?.+?)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$ | index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2] | page |
| [^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/?$ | index.php?attachment=$matches[1] | post |